# SQL CommandTimeout not working?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, sql-server-2005

I set the `CommandTimeout` property of my `SqlCommand` to 3 but it's still taking at least 10 seconds for it to throw an exception.

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("query", con)
cmd.CommandTimeout = 3
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Why you want to set timeout to 3 seconds?

Comment: What kind of exception you're getting? Is it sql exception thrown by your query, or is it connection timeout exception? You have to set connection timeout in the second case, not command timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Show yours connection options.
Note, that

> CommandTimeout has no effect when the command is executed against a context connection (a SqlConnection opened with "context connection=true" in the connection string).
>   [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)